# How to change pager key bindings

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, macos, less, pager, more

I'd like to swap `RETURN` (scroll  forward  N  lines,  default one window) and `SPACE` (scroll forward N lines, default 1) in `less` to get a for me more natural way to page through `man` pages.

I saw years ago a colleague having this setup during a `telnet` session to a router while he was skimming through a config file, so I don't actually know if this setting was on his SSH client, on the node or wherever.

Anyway, I'd like to achieve this to the most extent possible, be it locally or remotely.

I checked `less` man page's key bindings section and found a reference to [`lesskey`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lesskey&sektion=1).

Unfortunately, Darwin doesn't have this program.

Comment: Suggest migration to [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What is "more natural"? Usually `less` scrolls one line when hitting enter, and one screen when hitting the spacebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Darwin lacks `lesskey` (see [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27269/is-less1-missing-lesskey-functionality) and [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/less/less-23/defines.h)) I installed `less` 458 via MacPorts and added the bindings using the defaults path for my system. `lesskey` will take `$HOME/.lesskey` and output `$HOME/.less`. You can also use `LESSKEY` or `LESSKEY_SYSTEM`.

```
~ $ vi .lesskey
#command
\n        forw-screen
\40       forw-line
~ $ lesskey
~ $ ls -d .less*
.less       .lesshst    .lesskey
```

Answer (score 1):

You could install `less` via MacPorts or homebrew (or Fink!?), MacPorts at least has a `lesskey` containing `less` package:

```
% sudo port install less
...
% rehash
% which lesskey
/opt/local/bin/lesskey
%
```

This would then require `PATH` changes or a function for `less` so the ports-installed version of `less` gets picked up before the OS one, e.g.

```
function less {
  /opt/local/bin/less "$@"
}
```

Comment: I'll consider it, but I thought there might be a broader solution, like modifying the term file — still searching…